# NullPointerException in Listener class

Tags: pointers, exception, null, listener

Basically, I currently have this GUI:

[image]

What it's supposed to do is add all the highlighted items on the left scroll pane to the right scroll pane. However, whenever I press the "Add" button, I get a NullPointerException. The error happens in the ColumnMainPanel class under AddListener's actionPerformed when the *allColsPanel.getList().getSelectedValuesList()* gets executed.

My code looks like this:

*In the main frame:*

```
ColumnMainPanel columnsPanel = new ColumnMainPanel(allColumns);
frame.setContentPane(columnsPanel);
```

*ColumnMainPanel:*

```
public class ColumnMainPanel extends JPanel {
private AllColumnsPanel allColsPanel;
private SelectedColumnsPanel selColsPanel;
private CentralButtonsPane buttonPane;

public ColumnMainPanel() {
    allColsPanel = null;
    selColsPanel = null;
    buttonPane = null;
}

public ColumnMainPanel(String[] allColumns) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    this.dbe = d;
    setSize(250, 700);

    allColsPanel = new AllColumnsPanel(allColumns);
    selColsPanel = new SelectedColumnsPanel(allColumns.length);
    buttonPane = new CentralButtonsPane();

    add(allColsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(selColsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
}

class AddListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
        String[] columnsSelected;
// This next line is where I get the error:
        List<String> selectedValues = allColsPanel.getList().getSelectedValuesList();
        columnsSelected = new String[selectedValues.size()];
        columnsSelected = (selectedValues).toArray(columnsSelected);

        selColsPanel.addToList(columnsSelected);
    }
}

//add RemoveListener and ExportListener here
}
```

*AllColumnsPanel:*

```
public class AllColumnsPanel extends ColumnMainPanel implements ListSelectionListener {
private JList<String> list;
private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
private int numListItems;

public AllColumnsPanel(String[] allColumns) {
    setSize(300, 300);
    this.numListItems = allColumns.length;
    listModel = createListModel(allColumns);
    list = createList(listModel);

    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
    listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    add(listScrollPane);
}

public DefaultListModel<String> createListModel(String[] cols) {
    DefaultListModel<String> result = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < cols.length; i ++) {
        result.addElement(cols[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

public JList<String> createList(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
    JList<String> result = new JList<String>(listModel);
    result.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    result.setSelectedIndex(0);
    result.addListSelectionListener(this);
    result.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    return result;
}

public JList<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return numListItems < 1;
}
}
```

*CentralButtonsPane:*

```
public class CentralButtonsPane extends ColumnMainPanel {
private static final String addString = "Add";
private static final String removeString = "Remove";
private static final String exportString = "Export";

public CentralButtonsPane() {
    setLayout((new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)));
    setSize(50, 40);
    add(createAddButton());
    add(createRemoveButton());
    add(createExportButton());
}

public JButton createAddButton() {
    JButton result = new JButton(addString);
    result.setActionCommand(addString);
    result.setSize(50, 20);
    result.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    result.addActionListener(new AddListener());
    return result;
}
}
```

I checked the allColsPanel right after I initialize it in the ColumnMainPanel constructor and it's not null. However, when I checked if allColsPanel, under the AddListener, is null, it returns true. What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mhhls.him.dbtoexcelgui.main.ColumnMainPanel$AddListener.actionPerformed(ColumnMainPanel.java:53)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Add your exception with full stack trace to your question.

Comment: I do not see a constructor that matches the signature of your call.

Comment: Sorry, which constructor and which call are you talking about?

Comment: `new ColumnMainPanel(allColumns)` specifies a single parameter.  I do not see such constructor.

Comment: My bad, I just forgot to remove the other parameter when copy pasting. That wasn't the problem.